# Python: How to pass multiple keys at a time to dictionary

Tags: python, csv

I'm using `csv.DictReader` to read a `.csv` file.

`csv.DictReader` has an iterator which returns each row as a `dict` and I know how to get single column values out using the title of the columns:

```
CsvReaderRow[' D0']
CsvReaderRow[' D1']
CsvReaderRow[' D2']
CsvReaderRow[' D3']
CsvReaderRow[' D4']
CsvReaderRow[' D5']
CsvReaderRow[' CLOCK']
CsvReaderRow[' FRAME']
```

But is there a way to get out a bunch of columns with one statement?
I'd like to do

```
CsvReaderRow[(' D0', ' D1', ' D2', ' D3', ' D4', ' D5')]
```

and get a `list` of the values of those keys but it's giving me `KeyError`.

I understand that it's trying to hash the tuple and that it's not what I want.

I *could* create a list of `DX` and then use `for el in key_list` to index into the dict but I'm wondering if there's a more Pythonic way of doing this.

Comment: You could use that method if you were indexing a numpy array, but as it is your current solution seems optimal.

Comment: Either that or `whitelist = {' D0', ' D1', ' D2', ' D3', ' D4', ' D5'}; columns = [CsvReaderRow[col] for col in CsvReaderRow if col in whitelist]`

Comment: @AdamSmith shmancy! Put I'll try it when I get back to work tomorrow and if works, I'll accept. :)

Comment: Or `list(map(CsvReaderRow.get, [' D0', ' D1', ' D2', ' D3', ' D4', ' D5']))` (I'm kidding. That's ugly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described, the following approach should work nicely:

```
import csv

required = ['D0', 'D1', 'D2', 'D3', 'D4', 'D5']
entries = []

with open('input.csv', 'rb') as f_input:
    for dict_row in csv.DictReader(f_input):
        entries.append([dict_row[col] for col in required])
```

Or a bit more concise:

```
with open('input.csv', 'rb') as f_input:
    entries = [[dict_row[col] for col in required] for dict_row in csv.DictReader(f_input)]
```

Tested in Python 2.7.9

Comment: `entries.append([dict_row[col] for col in required])`: why is `dict_row[col] for col in required` valid syntax? It seems like you're using `col` before it exists. I don't doubt it works, I want to understand the syntax.

Comment: It is called a [`list comprehension`](https://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.0.html?highlight=list%20comprehension#list-comprehensions) and I agree it does look like it is used before

Answer (score 0):

Batteries included: [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter). Create a getter object:

```
 get_keys = operator.itemgetter(' D0', ' D1', ' D2', ' D3', ' D4', ' D5')
```

Then call the resulting object on each row:

```
with open('input.csv', 'rb') as f_input:  # Py3: open('input.csv', newline='')
    # list wrapper only required in Py3 (or Py2 if you imported map from future_builtins)
    entries = list(map(get_keys, csv.DictReader(f_input)))
```

Or calling explicitly if you hate `map` (or really want `list` of the values instead of the `tuple` an `itemgetter` returns for each call):

```
    entries = [list(get_keys(row)) for row in csv.DictReader(f_input)]
```

Comment: Note: This doesn't actually "pass all the keys at the same time". It's looking them up one-by-one, returning a `tuple` of the results. But it's packaging it into a simple preconstructed callable, and the callable (in CPython) is implemented at the C layer; no additional byte code is executed for each lookup, which can improve performance while reducing code complexity.